# JavaScript: cannot catch error from an async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

`handleEmailSubmit` function doesn't catch any errors even if `loginWithEmail` function throws an error.
Probably my lack of understanding of async functions.
i want your help. thank you.

Login.tsx

```
const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState<string>('');
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleEmailSubmit = useCallback(async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = e.target.elements;
    loginWithEmail(email.value, password.value)
      .then(() => {
        history.push('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // this block isn't called!
        setErrorMsg(error.message);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleEmailSubmit}>
        <InputGroup>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <TextField
            id="email"
            name="email"
            type="email"
          />
        </InputGroup>
        <InputGroup>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <TextField
            id="password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
          />
        </InputGroup>
        <Button type="submit">
          送信する
        </Button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

`loginWithEmail` definition

```
import axios from 'axios';

// firebase
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

export const loginWithEmail = async (
  email: string,
  password: string
): Promise<void> => {
  app
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      userCredential.user?.getIdToken(true).then((token: string) => {
        axios
          .get('https://dev.myserver.com/api/v1/users/auth', {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            app.auth().signOut();
            throw error;
          });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you missing `await` ?

Comment: You don't `return` the `axios.get()` call. So, you never get any error it might throw.

Comment: @francojay sorry, where should I need `await` on this code?

Comment: You neither return the Promise created by the chain you create with `app` nor do you have a `await` in `loginWithEmail`, due to that you break the promise chain and the error can’t propagate.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you for your advise! now I understand why my code doesn't work!
I added `await` to `loginWithEmail` function.

Answer (score 0):

To catch an error from an async function, you can use try/catch and await the error:

```
const handleEmailSubmit = useCallback(async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { email, password } = e.target.elements;
  try {
    await loginWithEmail(email.value, password.value);
    history.push('/');
  } catch(error) {
    const message = await error.message;
    setErrorMsg(message);
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to throw error in the catch statement.

```
app
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      userCredential.user?.getIdToken(true).then((token: string) => {
        axios
          .get('https://dev.myserver.com/api/v1/users/auth', {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            app.auth().signOut();
            throw error;
          });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      throw error; // there could be something wrong here
      
    });
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, but this doesn't work :(